# VBA to search files within a folder for a specific string and return file name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and coding and I'm currently using Excel 2013.
 I would like to search a specific string and it returns the file path where said string is in. Each file only have one sheet.

[image: example]

Is this possible? I've research into Dir and wildcard functions but I can't put it to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to loop through all the files in that folder, if you're trying to find a specific string within a workbook.

Comment: @BigBen let's say the folder has 4 workbooks, that would be 4 loops?

Comment: Nope, there you could use `Dir`.

Comment: Does each workbook have only one sheet?